# Custom title bar with ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in one of my activities. I also want to have a custom title bar in the same activity. So my onCreate method starts something like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        customTitle = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);    
        setContentView(R.layout.categorieslayout); //yup, i am not extending ListActivity, but just Activity
        setCustomTitleBar();
                ...
    }
```

When i run this, i get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

If i comment out the part where i request the window feature and call the function to set the custom title bar, it works fine. I am not sure how to get through this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: probably stupid request but can you replace the Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE with the number 7 and see what happenes (I forget how enums are in java. IDK for sure if you have to cast them or not...lol). As well as show the XML for the activity?

Comment: Do you have a ListView whose id is android.R.id.list?

Comment: +1 @ blindstuff for being on the same track.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're extending listactivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not related to custom title. You just need to fix your layout so it has explicit `ListView` declaration and that `ListView` shoud have a predefined id of `android.R.id.list`:

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list" ... />
```

Comment: +1 @ Arhimed because that is more than likely the answer that me and blindstuff were going to give anyway. lol